# How to load fragments the easy way?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an Activity that needs to load only 1 fragment.

Can I do something so that the Activity loads the fragment through the xml instead of using `FragmentManager`? Right now I have to write a Fragment class and that is not something I want to do.

This is how I do it.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private ExampleFragment fragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            fragment = new ExampleFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(frame.getId(), mFragment).commit();
        }

        setContentView(frame);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Right now I have to write a Fragment class and that is not something I want to do" -- then why are you trying to use fragments? The *point* behind fragments is to have subclasses of `Fragment` that manage portions of UI. You are certainly welcome to [use `<fragment>` tags instead of `FragmentTransaction`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding), but you still need the `Fragment` subclass.

Comment: What the point making Single Fragment ?? Fragment means to partition the main Activity into different parts.

Comment: @AjayShrestha There are logical reasons for having Activities that load the same fragment, but the Activity looks different.

Comment: @CommonsWare again the fragment is to load the same fragment into different Activities. In the future one Activity may have 2 fragments or more. For now this Activity has 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly the answer I was hoping for although it solves my question above so I am posting it. Maybe it helps someone. Cheers!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.MyFragment"
        android:id="@+id/myFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```